# How to format data from api response Angular HttpClient

Tags: json, angular, httpclient

I am trying to make an angular HttpClient get request but am having trouble with doing anything with the data.

I am using an api which is returning data in the form

```
(10)[{...}, {...}, {...}, ...]
[
0:{
   row: Array(4)
     0: "someid"
     1: "somename"
     2: "someaddress"
     3: "somepostcode"
  },
1:{
   row: Array(4)
     0: "someid"
     1: "somename"
     2: "someaddress"
     3: "somepostcode"
  },
2:{
   row: Array(4)
     0: "someid"
     1: "somename"
     2: "someaddress"
     3: "somepostcode"
  }, 
...
]
```

I just want to be able to create a list of objects with "someaddress" and "someid" fields from the get data. I have looked at various tutorials but keep getting undefined elements. How could you get the data from this.

Comment: you are getting an array of objects . run a loop and create your object

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like this:

```js
const data = [ // I have reformatted your returned data
    { row: ["someId", "somename", "someaddress"] },
    { row: ["someId", "somename", "someaddress"] },
    { row: ["someId", "somename", "someaddress"] },
    { row: ["someId", "somename", "someaddress"] }
];
    
const newData = data.map(item => ({ id: item.row[0], address: item.row[2] }));
    
console.log(newData);
```

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to type your HTTP responses, use the generic type :

```
interface MyInterface {
  row: string[];
}

return this.http.get<MyInterface[]>('URL');
```